# How to call api with MVVM in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, retrofit

I want call some API from server and for this I used **retrofit**!
I choose **MVVM** architecture for my project, I have **2 fragments**!
Fragment A and B . 
**Fragment A :** Call APIs and show list in `RecyclerView`.
**Fragment B :** Is detail page and show data info.
When tap on **back button** from device/emulator (in fragment B) and when show Fragment B, again call APIs!
I think when used `viewmodel`, APIS just call for first time!
I want just call APIs for first time!

**Repository class :**

```
class FragmentARepository @Inject constructor(private val api: ApiServices) {

    suspend fun dataList(): Flow<MyResponse<ResponseDataList>> {
        return flow {
            emit(MyResponse.loading())
            emit(MyResponse.success(api.dataList().body()))
        }.catch { emit(MyResponse.error(it.message.toString())) }.flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel class :**

```
@HiltViewModel
class FragmentAViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: FragmentARepository) : ViewModel() {

    val dalaListLive = MutableLiveData<List<ResponseDataList.Meal>>()
    fun loadDataList() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.dataList().collect { dataList.postValue(it.body()?.meals!!) }
    }
}
```

**Fragment A class :**

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //InitViews
        binding?.apply {
            viewModel.loadDataList()
            viewModel.dataList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                dataAdapter.setData(it.data.meals)
                                dataRv.setupRecyclerView(
                                    LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false),
                                    dataAdapter
                                )
                }
            }
}
```

Why my APIs call every time? **I want just one time.**
**I want just one time.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. ViewModels are not "calling API once". They call API whenever you request them to. In your FragmentA you request data from the view model from onViewCreated, which executes when you re-enter this fragment (e.g, when clicking *back* from FragmentB)

ViewModel however, is created and is persistent (up to a point):
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

So if you want to API call to occur once, you can call it inside your ViewModel's init:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class FragmentAViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: FragmentARepository) : ViewModel() {

    val dalaListLive = MutableLiveData<List<ResponseDataList.Meal>>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.dataList().collect {
            dataList.postValue(it.body()?.meals!!) 
        }
    }
}
```

And in your FragmentA just observe the *dalaListLive*:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //InitViews
        binding?.apply {
            viewModel.dataList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                dataAdapter.setData(it.data.meals)
                                dataRv.setupRecyclerView(
                                    LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false),
                                    dataAdapter
                                )
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        1) Get Api Call :-
           Api Name :- {{server}}auth/demoapi
           RestApi Call :-
            @GET(RestConstant.demoapi)  (Only Authorization) :-    
           suspend fun demoapi(@Header("Authorization") token: String): Response<LogoutResponse>
           @GET(RestConstant.CMSPAGE)   
          
          
        2) Authorization With Slug Pass
           Api Name :- {{server}}auth/demoapi/faq
           
           RestApi Call :-
           suspend fun demoapi(
                @Header("Authorization") token: String,
                @Path("slug") slug: String,
            ): Response<CmsPageResponse>
        
        
        
        3) Query Pass :-Params -> Query Params

            Api Name :-  https://google.com/api/demoapi?page=1&post_type=1
             
            @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
            @GET(RestConstant.demoapi)
            suspend fun demoapi(
                @Header("Authorization") token: String,
                @Query("search") search: String,
            ): Response<SendMyRequestResponse>
        
            {{server}}auth/demoapi  (Body - raw)
            {
        "search":""
    }
    val params = HashMap<String, String?>()
                params[UserParams.page] = page
    
        
        
        
        3) Delete
        
         @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
            @DELETE(RestConstant.demoapi)
            suspend fun demoapi(
                @Header("Authorization") token: String,
                @Path("user_id") user_id: String,
            ): Response<SuccessMainResponse>
            {{server}}auth/demoapi/47
        
        
        
        
        4) QueryMap
            val params = HashMap<String, String?>()
                    params[UserParams.page] = page
        
               @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
            @GET(RestConstant.demoapi)
            suspend fun demoapi(
                @Header("Authorization") token: String,
                @QueryMap params: HashMap<String, String?>,
            ): Response<PostListPageResponse>
        
        
        
        
        
        5)  POST
            val params = HashMap<String, String?>()
             @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
            @POST(RestConstant.demoapi)
            suspend fun demoapi(
                @Header("Authorization") token: String,
                @Body params: java.util.HashMap<String, String?>,
            ): Response<SuccessMainResponse>
        
        
        6) POST Calling Api post Raw Body
        {
            "mobile_no":"54",
         
        }   
        
        @FormUrlEncoded
            @POST(RestConstant.demoapi)
            suspend fun demoapi(@FieldMap params: java.util.HashMap<String, String>): Response<LoginResponse>    
        
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                            params.put(UserParams.mobile_no, binding.etPhone.text.toString())
        
        
        
         7) Multiple Part  FORM DATA
          
            @Multipart
            @POST(RestConstant.demoapi)
            suspend fun demoapi(
                @PartMap params: HashMap<String, RequestBody?>,
                @Part id_proof: MultipartBody.Part?,
                @Part certificate: MultipartBody.Part?
            ): Response<LoginResponse>                   
        
        
             val params = HashMap<String, RequestBody?>()
                params[UserParams.first_name] = AppUtils.getRequestBody(binding.etFirstName.text.toString())
        
                   fun getRequestBody(value: String?): RequestBody? {
                return value!!.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            }
        
        
             var body2: MultipartBody.Part? = null
                if (picturePath2!!.isNotEmpty())
                {
                    val file = File(picturePath2)
                    val requestFile = RequestBody.create("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)
                    body2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(UserParams.latest_certificate, file.name, requestFile)
                }
                registerApis(params, /*body, */ body1,body2)




8) Api Name:-   "auth/demoApi/{user_id}"
PUT Method :- raw body JSONOBJECT
{
    "is_live":"1"
}

 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @PUT(RestConstant.demoApi)
    suspend fun demoApi(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Path("user_id") slug: String,
        @Body params: RequestBody,
    ): Response<Response>

suspend fun demoapi(token1: String, slug1: String, @Body params1: RequestBody) =
        RetrofitClient.apiInterface.demoapi(
            token = token1,
            slug = slug1,
            params = params1
        )


val params = HashMap<String, Any?>()
params[UserParams.is_live] = "1"
""...
val body: RequestBody = JSONObject(params).toString()
                .toRequestBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())
Call Api and Pass the body for JSONBODY
```

Comment: Please, edit your code block. Make it separate for each step. Use 4 spaces for correct line space formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initilize empty list
var countryList = ArrayList<DataItem?>()



// Assign value
countryList.clear()
countryList = gradeListResponse.data as ArrayList<DataItem?>


// Set Custom Adapter
val adapter = CountryListAdapter(countryList)
        val mLayoutManager1: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 1)
        rvSubjectList.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        rvSubjectList.layoutManager = mLayoutManager1
        rvSubjectList.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setOnItemClickLister(object :
            CountryListAdapter.OnItemClickLister {
            override fun itemClicked(view: View?, position: Int, dataItem: DataItem?) {
                binding.etCountry.setText(countryList[position]!!.name.toString())
                dialog.dismiss()
                viewModel.statesListApi(countryList[position]!!.id.toString())
            }
        })




// Adapter

class CountryListAdapter(
    private var answerList: ArrayList<DataItem?>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryListAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
{
    private var onItemClickLister: OnItemClickLister? = null
    private lateinit var context: Context
    var selectedPosition = -1

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {
        var txtSubjectName: AppCompatTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubjectName)
        var ivRadioBtn: AppCompatImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivRadioBtn)
        override fun onClick(v: View) {

        }

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        context = parent.context

        val deals = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.row_country_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(deals)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return answerList.size
    }

    interface OnItemClickLister {
        fun itemClicked(view: View?, position: Int, dataItem: DataItem?)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickLister(onItemClickLister: OnItemClickLister?)
    {
        this.onItemClickLister = onItemClickLister
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtSubjectName.text = answerList[position]!!.name.toString()
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener()
        {
            selectedPosition = position
            onItemClickLister!!.itemClicked(holder.itemView, position,answerList[position])
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        if (selectedPosition == position) {
            holder.ivRadioBtn.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
            holder.ivRadioBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_btn_checkd)

        } else {
            holder.ivRadioBtn.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
            holder.ivRadioBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_btn_unchecked)
        }
    }

    fun updateList(filterdNames: ArrayList<DataItem?>)
    {
        this.answerList=filterdNames
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}



    fun BottomSheetDialog() {
        lateinit var dialog: BottomSheetDialog

        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_bottom_sheet, null)
        val rvSubjectList: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvSubjectList)
        val etSearchOnly: AppCompatEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.etSearchOnly)

        val adapter = StateListAdapter(statesList)
        val mLayoutManager1: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 1)
        rvSubjectList.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        rvSubjectList.layoutManager = mLayoutManager1
        rvSubjectList.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setOnItemClickLister(object :
            StateListAdapter.OnItemClickLister {
            override fun itemClicked(
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                dataItem: DataItem
            ) {
                binding.etState.setText(statesList[position].name.toString())
                dialog.dismiss()
                viewModel.cityListApi(statesList[position].id.toString())
            }
        })
        etSearchOnly.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                count: Int, after: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                before: Int, count: Int
            ) {
                filter(s.toString())
            }

            fun filter(text: String) {
                val filterdNames = ArrayList<DataItem>()
                if (statesList.size > 0)
                {
                    for (test_datalist in statesList)
                    {
                        if (test_datalist!!.name!!.lowercase(Locale.ROOT)
                                .contains(text.lowercase(Locale.ROOT))
                        ) {
                            filterdNames.add(test_datalist)
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.updateList(filterdNames)
                }
            }
        })

        dialog.setCancelable(true)
        dialog.setContentView(view)
        dialog.show()
    }
```